# Mouse lags in VirtualBox

Tags: mouse, virtualization, virtualbox

I want to use VirtualBox on my MacBook Pro. I allocated 8G memory and 4 cores as CPU to the VirtualBox. I have installed Windows 8.1 Pro. But I realize that the mouse still lags in Windows.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: 8GB & 4 cores out of how many, total?

Comment: out of 16GB & 8 cores.

Comment: Did you install vbox additions in the VM?  Once you do that, the lagging should stop.

Comment: Is it [this one](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html)? @Allan

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to on that page.  You need to install the [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)